# AWS Athena can access Glue catablog but queries return zero rows

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-glue, amazon-athena

There seems to be a permission problem with am AWS Athena but I can't figure out where?

I browse the glue tables (which represent crawled S3 csv files) and whichever I try to "preview" or list, I get zero rows.

Comment: Is your table partitioned? If yes, you need to add (discover) partitions first.

Comment: Can you confirm if the table is pointed to a file or a folder ? You can verify by running "show create table <table-name>"

Answer (score 0):

If your table is partitioned, you need to run `MSCK REPAIR TABLE` first, to discover those partitions. More information on that [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/msck-repair-table.html).

Comment: Thanks. How do I know whether it is partitioned? And where I can run this command? It is refused as athena query.

Comment: You can run SHOW PARTITIONS table_name to see if a table is partitioned