# Aws Athena Spark returns empty Glue table

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, amazon-athena

I have an AWS Glue table which points to an S3 location (let's say `s3://bucket-name/root-folder`)
Under the `root-folder` I have multiple folders (let's say `1`, `2`, `3` etc).
Under each of these folders I have a few parquet files.

I created a GLue table that points to the `root-folder` without partitions.
When I run the query using Athena query editor I get results as I expect, they contain the data from all the 1,2,3 folders.
The query I run:

```
select count(*) from db_name.table_name
```

When I run the same query using Athena notebooks with spark, I get an empty table:
The code that I run:

```
spark.sql("select count(*) from db_name.table_name").count()
```

The following code also doesn't work and returns 0:

```
spark.read.table("db_name.table_name").count()
```

When I run `show()` instead of `count()` I get the correct schema but the table is empty.

When I run the following code in Athena spark I get proper results:

```
spark.read.option("recursiveFileLookup", "true").parquet("s3a://bucket-name/root-folder/").count()
```

The IAM role for the workgroup contains the following (Very widely open) permissions:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "glue:SearchTables",
                "glue:GetTables",
                "glue:GetTableVersions",
                "glue:GetPartitions",
                "glue:BatchGetPartition",
                "glue:GetDatabases",
                "glue:GetPartitionIndexes",
                "glue:GetTable",
                "glue:GetDatabase",
                "glue:GetPartition",
                "glue:GetTableVersion",
                "glue:GetUserDefinedFunction",
                "glue:GetColumnStatisticsForTable",
                "glue:GetUserDefinedFunctions",
                "glue:GetColumnStatisticsForPartition"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:glue:eu-central-1:MY_ACCOUNT:catalog",
                "arn:aws:glue:eu-central-1:MY_ACCOUNT:table/db_name/*",
                "arn:aws:glue:eu-central-1:MY_ACCOUNT:database/db_name"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "s3:List*",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::bucket-name/*",
                "arn:aws:s3:::bucket-name"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor3",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "s3:Get*",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::bucket-name/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I can't understand what's the issue

Comment: Related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67208999/aws-athena-can-access-glue-catablog-but-queries-return-zero-rows